# ASP.NET HttpModule : detect first request in a session

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

I have written a HttpModule for our site which generally accepts requests and checks for specific file extensions as well as the value of a specific session variable. Is it possible to detect the first request in a session?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a property on [HttpSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx) you can use called [IsNewSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.isnewsession.aspx), e.g.:

```
if(Context.Session != null && Context.Session.IsNewSession) {
  //do something, session was created this request
}
```

You can only do this after session state is available of course, but from what you're doing in your module, that doesn't seem to be a problem, please comment if it is.